# How does same origin policy (SOP) work?

Tags: javascript, same-origin-policy

I had a read of what same origin policy means on Wikipedia however fail to understand how it works. I do understand that it prevents for example a javascript on my website from interacting with a script on a separate site however what does this exactly mean?

Comment: Not posting an answer, because it's just a link to [MDN - Same Origin Policy for JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your script (JS) tries to perform some HTTP request to the site other than the one it originated from via XMLHttpRequest, the request will fail, return status code will be 0 and error message - null.

That's how it worked originally.

Right now there is a Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) specification, which is more or less supported by most modern browsers. It allows to do such requests, but with strict limitations.

Comment: Thanks but am confused by the statement `perform some HTTP request to the site other than the one it originated from via XMLHttpRequest`. What do you mean by `to the site than the one it originated from`? Do you mean if I load a website e.g. www.example.com and javascript is loaded with that webpage and it (JS) attempts to make a XMLHTTP request to say www.example1.com, it would fail. Is that right?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: yes, exactly. Also the subdomain and port number will count, for example, if your script is loaded from `http://localhost/examplescript.js` then XMLHttpRequest in it WILL be able to access `http://localhost/something` but will fail to access `http://www.localhost/something` or `http://localhost:8080/something`

Comment: Thanks. I take it however it can traverse unlimited number of sub-directories e.g. http://localhost/sub1/sub2/sub3, etc? This wouldn't matter if I were using IFRAME would it i.e. a page that loads another page from another domain via an IFRAME? Also is same origin policy limited to JS?

Comment: First, yes, traverse is unlimited (well, limited by general url length restrictions etc., not by SOP). Second, IFRAME will be a subject to analogous restriction, just for the domain it has been loaded from. I.e. if you have a page loaded from [example.com] and IFRAME has a source [example1.com] then Javascript within IFRAME will have access to all [example1.com] resources but no access to [example.com]. Third: yes, it's limited to JS XMLHttpRequest object.

Comment: Thanks. When you say it is limited to JS XMLHTTPRequest, I take it you are only referring to sites that utilize JS but what about sites that utilize Java or Flash, etc?

Comment: I also don't quite follow what `There is one exception to the same origin rule. A script can set the value of document.domain to a suffix of the current domain` means exactly which is documented at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript?

Comment: Java and Flash used on client side are beyond my knowledge, sorry :( 
For your second question - if the script originates from `subdomain.example.com` then by default it can make XMLHttpRequests only to `subdomain.example.com`, respectively. But if somewhere inside the script a statement `document.domain = "example.com";` is executed then XMLHttpRequest issued after that statement will be allowed by a browser to do a query to `example.com` without subdomain.

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean that `document.domain = "example.com"` is limited to a specific domain? For example if the script originates from subdomain.example.com can `document.domain = xyz.com` occur or is it limited to `document.domain = example.com`?

Comment: Second is right, `document.domain` assignment is limited to `example.com` in my example.

Comment: Thanks. Please forgive my noobness but when you say in your example, I wanted to make sure that `document.domain = xyz.com` cannot occur if the script is being loaded from subdomain.example.com or in any instance i.e. that `document.domain` is limited to the domain in use be it example.com, abc.com, etc

Comment: That's fine :) And as I said, it is limited that way.

Comment: Sorry but I still don't understand the use of `limited that way`. Do you mean it is limited to the primary domain i.e. example.com if the secondary domain is subdomain.example.com? So if that is the case I can't have `document.domain = xyz.com`. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

it means if you load

http://www.stackoverflow.com/

and your browser loads javascript, then that javascript cannot access a url that doesn't come from that page.  There are a lot of details, for example, you could not access

https://www.stackoverflow.com

but an ajax request could access

http://www.stackoverflow.com/something/something

The browser itself would not allow the request to be fired.

EDIT -- This might be helfpul: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=171316324d16747b&hl=en

Comment: yes, meaning the browser wont send the request because it violates the same origin policy

Comment: Right and correct me I am wrong. The reason being it can't is because it is a different protocol however it raises the question what do you mean 'access'. Is the javascript attempting to access information from the same site but on a different protocol and hence failing? What does is 'this' information? Can it be anything?